# How does the "Privacy Protection" option from domain names registrars work?

Tags: privacy, dns, dns-domain

Some domain names registrars are offering a "Privacy Protection" option to hide your registrant details. Your `whois` infos will then refer to the "privacy company" providing this service instead of the ones you entered with your registrar. How do those services technically work, and what are their benefits compared to simply entering bogus information?

Answer (score 1):

They "technically" work by providing the company name and address to the whois database instead of yours.  That's it.

The main advantage is that you don't get your domain revoked for providing bogus information.  And you can still be contacted through the registration company where needed.

Comment: I'm still missing the whole point,  why does the registrar need to use a third party service to do this ? And do ppl *really* get their domain revoked for providing bogus informations ?